# jest with typescript throws an error when importing a file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I'm having issues with jest on typescript.

```
//myprovider.tsx

class MyProvider{
   constructor(){}
   giveMeFive(): int{  return 5;  }
}

export { MyProvider }



// myprovider.test.js

import { MyProvider } from './myprovider';

test('give me five!', () => {
  const myprovider = new MyProvider();
  /// assert
})
```

I get the following error

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

import { MyProvider } from './myprovider';
       ^
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I have this on my package

```
//package.json

  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/tests/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js"]
  },



// .babelrc

{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
} 



//jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
}
```

Comment: Do you get the error if you export the class directly instead of at the bottom of the file like that? i.e. export class MyProvider{ etc...

Otherwise I'd say change export { MyProvider } to export default MyProvider and import in your test without the brackets

Comment: yeah same, i did both of your suggestions

Comment: It could be because you're not importing react in the test, on a side note your file isn't actually a react component, you can make it a ts file instead of tsx. Otherwise "import * as React from 'react'" in your test file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to install these packages:

`babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env`

Your babel config should look like this:

```
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "current",
        },
      },
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ]
```

Comment: this worked. thanks! follow up tho, i thought you did not need to add a babel preset once you have tsconfig.js set and jest.config.js to transform tsx to js?

Comment: Tsconfig transpile your code in the `build` step. Right now your are not building your application. `Babel` transpile your code for `Jest`. @gdubs

Comment: [@babel/preset-typescript](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript) is missing in your answer regarding installing.